# passing array to <option> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a custom multiselect option box and I need to pass an array of selected values to the element

```
var data=[];
$(".opt > div").click(function(){
  data[data.length]=$(this).attr("value");
  $(".options").val(data);  // putting data into custom option
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- own custom style -->
  <select class="options"> <!-- select is hidden with CSS -->
    <!-- options -->
  </select>
</div>

<div class="opt"> <!-- this div is dynamically created by clicking         no class wrapper and populated the inside with select box's options with jQuery -->
  <div value="0">item 1</div>
  <div value="1">item 2</div> 
  <div value="2">item 3</div> 
</div>
```

Everything is going well But on click event I want to value .option class with array 'data' and pass it via It's form on submit as request. How to set array (data) as It's value?

Like in checkbox, giving name like **name="somename[]"** makes the response an array.
Or an

*the above code is just a brief demonstration of What I want*

Comment: You should take the problem in reverse. Make your select with its options in the html. Then hide it with `CSS`, and dynamicly construct the "custom multiselect" with `jQuery`. Don't forget to add the `multiple` attribute to your `select` : `<select multiple="multiple">`

Answer (score 1):

First, make your select multi and give it a name:

```
<select name="cmbSomeName" class="options" multiple="multiple">
```

Second, on the click, reset your select options and reselect select all that are in the data array.

```
var data=[];
$(".opt > div").click(function(){
   data[data.length]=$(this).attr('value');

   //Unselect all the options
   $('.options option').each(function(){ this.selected = false; })

   //For each item in data, select the respective option in the select
   $.each(data, function(){
      $('.options options[value="' + this + '"]').prop('selected', true);
   });
});
```

Finally, when you submits your form, the cmbSomeName will be an array in the server side

Its important to note that this code will always increase the data[] array, so, you will not be enable to "unselect" those itens, for such, I would do diferent coding like so:

```
 $(".opt > div").click(function(){
      jqOption = $('.options options[value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]');

      //Toggle (if true then false else true)
      jqOption.prop('selected', !jqOption.prop('selected'));
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
$(".options").append(data);
```

Dont use value for writing html

Comment: I'm not writing HTML, I'm  trying to value the <select> with jQuery as it naturally happens in normal <select> box

Comment: @Ario That's not how a `<select>` works. The value is contained in `<option>` elements in it.

Comment: But I made the same thing for a single value

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ateqiDa/7/edit)

The trick is to:

- Clone the select `options`
- Put them inside a `DIV` (ok, who cares, it works beautifully)
- target the original Select element on DIV click:

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- note! it wraps the select and the .opt -->
  <select class="options" multiple>
    <option value="0">Item 1</option>
    <option value="1">Item 2</option>
    <option value="2">Item 3</option>
  </select>
  <div class="opt"></div> <!-- will be populated by jQ -->
</div>
```

```
$('.options').each(function(){ 
  $(this).next('.opt').html($(this).html());
});

$('.opt').on('click', 'option', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected')
         .parent().prev('select')
         .find('option[value='+ this.value +']')[0].selected ^= 1;
});
```

with this basic CSS:

```
.opt option{
  background:#eee;
  border-bottom:1px solid #888;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.opt option:hover{
  background:#ddd;
}
.opt option.selected{
  background:#cf5;
}
```

Comment: yes But I want to pass multiple values. Like value 0 and 1 together

Comment: @Ario : Do you mean 0 and item1 or (1 and item2 )?

Comment: I mean value 0 and 1 (of attribute data-value)

Comment: @Ario than you **don't want** a `select` dropdown :) cause that's not how `<select>` works... Or I understand your question totally wrong ...

Comment: @Ario you want actually a `select multiple`, right? Cause in yout HTML example you did not stated that it's a `multiple` as attribute

Comment: Ummm I see :'( then What should I do. All I want is to make some multiple selectable items (custom) and pass it with a form. Somewhat like a <select multiple="multiple"> works @roko

Comment: @Ario there you go. Edited and created a demo